# html decimal coded string

Tags: php

I'm parsing html from a website using simplehtmldom_1_5, when i echo the parsed text to the screen it's printed correctly but when i try to save it to a file using file_put_contents i've my string coded to html decimal code :

&#40&#98&#46&#32&#97&#110&#100&#101&#114&#115&#115&#111&#110&#44&#32

i've already tried all possible combination of utf8_encode, utf8_decode, htmlentities... but nothing worked, same problem when i try to insert to mysql table.
mb_detect_encoding for the parsed text returns ASCII.
Any suggestions ?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

include 'simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html($curr_url);
$texts = $html->find('div[id=content_h]');
foreach($texts as $text) {
    file_put_contents('queries.txt', $text->innertext . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: i've added some code but it's a simple html parsing using simple html dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also try html_entity_decode ( https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode ) ?
Thats the function converting entities back to clear type text

*edit

I just tested this to verify it's working.

Yes it works, BUT:

your data is *incorrect* !
Every single entity is missing a semicolon at its end!

Thats why decoding only works in loose browser-render engines...

Your data shall be looking like this:

```
&#40;&#98;&#46;
```

and not like this

```
&#40&#98&#46
```

See the difference?

Comment: i've tried this
preg_replace('/&#(\d+)/me',"chr(\\1)", $text)
And it worked for me

Comment: Of course it does, because it takes the ASCII value of each the entities and converts them back using the PHP function which is designed for converting the ASCII representing number back to the character it stands for. Never the less your data seems not to be conisting of valid html entity for they are missing the ;

Answer (score 1):

Finally this worked for me

```
preg_replace('/&#(\d+)/me',"chr(\\1)", $text)
```